# Sorting array is not happening

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this and I wnat to ignore first two object and then sort the based on its ISD code in ascdeing order.

My data

```
"Output" : 
    [{
        Name:"Country"
    },{
        Name :"CODE"
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Alex",
        "Country" :"India",
        "CODE": "91"

    },{
        "Name" : "David",
        "Country" : "USA",
        "CODE": "1"
    },{
        "Name" :"Ravi",
        "Country" : "NZ"
        "CODE": "61"
    },{
        "Name" :"Smith",
        "Country" : "AUS"
        "CODE": "64"
    }
    ]
```

What I am trying here is

```
var sortedData = sortByKey(output,"CODE")
function sortByKey(array, key) {
        return array.sort(function(a, b) {
            var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
            return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
        });
    }
```

But it is rearranging the data rendomly. CAn anyone help me what is going wrong here.

Comment: You are trying to sort by key “ISD”, but there is actually no such key in the objects in your array

Comment: @PatrickHund I updated my question.

Comment: `parseInt()` is what you're looking for when comparing the CODEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You coudld take `localeCompare` with some options for sorting numerical values in the right order.

```js
function sortByKey(array, key) {
    var temp = array.slice(2);

    temp.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (a[key] || '').localeCompare(b[key] || '', undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' });
    });
    return array.slice(0, 2).concat(temp);
}

var array = [{ Name: "Country" }, { Name: "CODE" }, { Name: "Alex", Country: "India", CODE: "2" }, { Name: "David", Country: "USA", CODE: "1" }, { Name: "Ravi", Country: "NZ", CODE: "11" }, { Name: "Smith", Country: "AUS", CODE: "24" }];

console.log(sortByKey(array, "CODE"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I updated my question. I am sorting based on some key. Also ignoring first two element of json.

Comment: in your output I can not see sorting order. This is just displaying arry in ther order which decleared

Comment: in your output I can not see sorting order. This is just displaying arry in ther order which decleared. But it worked for my code. thanks

Comment: Yes I noted that

Comment: In your code `localeCompare` of undefined. Ok let me figure it out. I will test and let you know

Comment: you could add some default values, like `''` for `undefined`.

Comment: Ya, doing the same. Thanks for `loadcompare` idea :)

Comment: One quick question. How you do you write such smart code which really good by content wise. Iove if you share the trick. :)

Comment: it's just a long time of experience.

Answer (score 1):

This should works, hope it helps!

```js
var data = [
    { "Name": "Country" },
    { "Name": "CODE" },
    { "Name": "Alex", "Country": "India", "CODE": "91" },
    { "Name": "David", "Country": "USA", "CODE": "1" },
    { "Name": "Ravi", "Country": "NZ", "CODE": "61" },
    { "Name": "Smith", "Country": "AUS", "CODE": "64" }
];

var sortedJSON = sortByKey(data, "CODE");

function sortByKey(array, key) {
    var others = [], result;

    result = array.filter(function(o) {
        if (!o[key]) others.push(o);
        return (o[key]);
    }).sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key], y = b[key];
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
    
    return others.concat(result);
}

console.log(sortedJSON);
```

Comment: Here I am loosing first two data

Comment: I thought you ask to ignore the first two data?

Comment: take out the first two elements from your json object, sort the rest then merge them again

Comment: Igoner during sorting because there is no order in that

Comment: Updated to not delete element without sorting property

Answer (score 1):

This is working perfectly. If you are looking for numeric sort use parseFloat
If you don't need the data with `CODE` key use below method

`

```js
var JSON = {
    "Output": [
        {Name: "Country"}, 
        {Name: "CODE"},
        {"Name": "Alex","Country": "India","CODE": "91"},
        {"Name": "David","Country": "USA","CODE": "1"}, 
        {"Name": "Ravi","Country": "NZ","CODE": "61"}, 
        {"Name": "Smith","Country": "AUS","CODE": "64"}]
}
var sortedJSON = sortByKey(JSON.Output, "CODE");
console.log(sortedJSON);
function sortByKey(array, key) {
    for (var obj in array) {
       if(array[obj][key] === undefined) {
         delete array[obj];
       }
    }
    return array.sort(function (a, b) {
        if(a[key] && b[key]){
            var x = parseInt(a[key]);
            var y = parseInt(b[key]);
            return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to keep the objects without code use the one below

```js
var JSON = {
    "Output": [
        {Name: "Country"}, 
        {Name: "CODE"},
        {"Name": "Alex","Country": "India","CODE": "91"},
        {"Name": "David","Country": "USA","CODE": "1"}, 
        {"Name": "Ravi","Country": "NZ","CODE": "61"}, 
        {"Name": "Smith","Country": "AUS","CODE": "64"}]
}
var sortedJSON = sortByKey(JSON.Output, "CODE");
console.log(sortedJSON);
function sortByKey(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function (a, b) {
        if(a[key] && b[key]){
            var x = parseInt(a[key]);
            var y = parseInt(b[key]);
            return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In first one I don't want to loose first two data. I want just ignore during sorting.

Comment: @David then you can use the second one